# Windows Services C# doesn't call method on stop when kill from task manager

Tags: c#, windows, service, process, windows-services

I am developing a Windows Services project using visual studio 2019. I created my service and everything is ok, it is running, calling my tasks from time to time!

But when I end the process through the task manager, my service stops without calling the onStop () method.

If I go to the task manager -> services and stop my service there, it calls onStop () normally and does what it has to do..

I'm trying to develop a kind of "anti hacker" for an online game server. If I can finish my service this way without causing it to fall into the onStop () method, my anti hacker will not work!

Anyone can help me?

my method onStop:

```
  protected override void OnStop()
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("taskkill", "/F /T /IM androidapp")
                {
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    WorkingDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true
                };
                Process.Start(processStartInfo);
            }
            catch { }   
        }
```

Comment: This is the normal behavior of Windows.
You develop Windows service and all the features work fine as Windows service manner.

Think to service as a proxy or layer, when you kill it by its process the layer chain bypassed!

Comment: @MojtabaTajik I edit my topic, what can i do to not allow a process to be terminated directly?

Comment: @MickyD I'm trying to develop a kind of "anti hacker" for an online game server. So I'm thinking as a user that is going to end this service through the task manager. And if he finishes the process, he will be able to use the illicit programs.

Comment: It's not totally about the process but user permission.
For your purpose, you need to develop a kernel driver.

C# is not a good choice to develop this type of tool.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/early-launch-antimalware?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/protecting-anti-malware-services-?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: _"what can i do to not allow a process to be terminated directly?"_ - you can't, try another way, like making 2 services which restarting each other, when some one of them goes down

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the update to your question

Comment: @vasily.sib hmmm... I'll try to do this ! Thanks Vasily!

Comment: You can configure a Windows service to have the SCM automatically restart the service after a failure. You can do it from the Services applet or through scripting the SCM. I think, but I'm not sure that you can do it with a standard Installee component